# Select DataGridViewColumn by DataPropertyName

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in which i need to select the a cell of a specific column programatically. But the designer autogenerates this:

```
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.DataPropertyName = "NameIWant";
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.HeaderText = "NameIWant";
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1";
```

And this does nothing.

```
DataGridViewColumn column = DataGridView.Columns["NameIWant"];
```

Is there anyway to get a column by his DataPropertyName or to set automaticaly the name of the column?
The DataGridView is binded to a DataSet which reads from an SQL Server.

Comment: Your SQL Query can have in the string  Name as NameIWant.  Then when you use datagridview1.DataSource = ds you get the name you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add form field:

```
Dictionary<string, DataGridViewColumn> columnDictionary;
```

fill it in with the data:

```
columnDictionary = dataGridView.Columns
    .OfType<DataGridViewColumn>()
    .ToDictionary(c => c.DataPropertyName, c => c);
```

Use it:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = columnDictionary["NameIWant"];
```